# Print out contents of a file using ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

I want to print out the results of a text file in ansible using cat. This is my code.

```
 tasks:
        - name: This option
          script: "./getIt.py -s {{ myhostname }} -u {{ myuser }} -p {{ mypass }} >> ./It.txt"
          shell: cat ./It.txt
          when: user_option == 'L'
```

This however doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to call two different modules from a single task: script and shell. You need to break them up... one module per task! However, there's a better way to do it by capturing the output of the script with [register](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables), and using the [debug](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html) module in a subsequent task to display it:

```
tasks:
  - name: This option
    script: "./getIt.py -s {{ myhostname }} -u {{ myuser }} -p {{ mypass }}"
    register: script
    when: user_option == 'L'
  - name: stdout of getIt
    debug: msg={{ script.stdout }}
    when: script is defined and script|succeeded
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. One more thing though. I made it stdout_lines. This for anyone who has multiple lines in the file like i do.

Comment: I guess you've meant `success` filter.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov There's a note on the conditionals page: "the filters have been updated in 2.1 so both success and succeeded work (fail/failed, etc)."